# c++ empty char array has length > 0

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Had a basic c++ question. I find char array not initialized are having length > 0. Can someone explain ?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char test1[5];
    test1[4] = 0;
    printf("test1 array %s, length %d\n", test1, strlen(test1));

    char test2[128];
    test2[127] = 0;
    printf("test2 array %s, length %d\n", test2, strlen(test2));
}
```

This prints (why empty and zero length for the first array and non-empty and non-zero length for the second array)?:

```
test1 array , length 0
test2 array 8??, length 6
```

Comment: Since you're using C++ it's really important to learn about things like `std::vector` and `std::string`. `strlen` is C code and doesn't belong here unless your goal is to write C code.

Comment: If you don't initialize your variables they can be full of anything, including 6 non 0 bytes in a row.

Comment: As you may now arrays are fixed size containers at compile-time. So when you create the array whatever you initialize it or not, it has the memory allocated.

Comment: *I find char array not initialized are having length > 0.* -- I don't really understand why you're surprised.  If it isn't initialized, what did you expect?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's really my question too upon seeing this. null terminating the arrays demonstrates some knowledge about how things work. If the assumption was that uninitialized arrays were all zero then there would be no reason to explicitly null terminate them.

Comment: Please retag your question as C, this has nothing to do with C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard `C` strings end at a null-terminator, which your uninitialized data may or may not have anywhere in it.  I think other answers have covered that already.

And while this may seem pedantic and you may already know it, the length of a char array is NOT the same as the length of the string of it contains (if it contains one).  The output of `sizeof()` on your variables is NOT undefined, because it doesn't look at the contents at all:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char test1[5];
    test1[4] = 0;
    printf("test1 array %s, string length %d array length %d\n", test1, strlen(test1), sizeof(test1)/sizeof(char));

    char test2[128];
    test2[127] = 0;
    printf("test2 array %s, string length %d array length %d\n", test2, strlen(test2), sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char));
}
```

Output:

```
test1 array , string length 0 array length 5
test2 array P`, string length 3 array length 128
```

One last note.  NULL-terminated strings are problematic.  Anytime you find yourself using them in `C++` instead of `std::string` you should be able to answer the question "why?"  There are reasons....but you should have one.

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't initialized those values you're getting *undefined behaviour*. That is they can contain anything. Maybe zeroes, maybe random data.

Passing an uninitialized character buffer to `printf` is undefined behaviour and should not be done. That might work, it might not. The only way to get defined behaviour is to initialize it properly.

Comment: Looks like you're interested in C++ without reading much into the standards. UB != uninitialized or indeterminate values.

Comment: @iBug Operations on indeterminate values may cause UB  (and do, in this case)

Answer (score 1):

The problem:

```
char test1[5]; // no initialization
test1[4] = 0;  // this is assignment not initialization
```

As per [dcl.init/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#12)

> When storage for an object with *automatic* or dynamic storage
>   duration is obtained, the object has an **indeterminate value**, and
>   if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains
>   an indeterminate value until that value is replaced.

Thus, `test1` has *indeterminate value*.

Using this variable in functions is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score -1):

The initializing code 'test2[127] = 0;' is not correct. You should initialize the char array as following:

```
char test2[128]={0};
```

Or

```
char test2[128];
test2[0] = 0;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what the user has done, it is perfectly valid code. As it stands I don't believe this answers the question, but perhaps if you add more explanation it might.

Comment: This answer tip-toes around the solution without coming out and saying what went wrong and why the initialization change solves the problem. Not worth a downvote, but not worth an upvote, either.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the original code is not valid; it passes indeterminate values to a C library function

Comment: @RetiredNinja It is apparently not perfectly valid code. Though grammatically valid, it is logically incorrect. To initialize the char array to a empty string, the code  `test2[127] = 0;`  is not correct, instead it should be `test2[0] = 0;` or  `char test2[128]={0}`.

Comment: The code shown is syntactically correct. To say it is incorrect assumes the OP is looking to do something that is not mentioned in the question. This would be a fine answer to "How do I initialize an array to all zeros?", but that isn't the question being asked.